# python: iterate using a class method

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm still digging in python, and there are a few things that my C++ background is getting in the way. For example, I have a class

```
class crack(object):

   def __init__(self, sz1,sz2):
        self.z1 = sz1
        self.z2 = sz2

   def smallz_Z(self,z,z1,z2):
       return z - 0.5*(z2-z1)

   def get_pot(self,z):
        Z = smallz_Z(z,self.z1,self.z2)

        try:
             result = np.sum(np.arange(self.n) * self.coeffs * (1.0 / (cmath.sqrt(Z - 1.0) * cmath.sqrt(Z + 1.0))) 
                        * ((Z - cmath.sqrt(Z - 1.0) * cmath.sqrt(Z + 1.0)) ** np.arange(self.n))) * (2.0 / (self.z2 - self.z1))
```

I'm going to create a list for crack elements,

```
crack_list = []
crack_list.append(crack(z1,z2)) ...
```

And now I need to use a iterator to get all the values of potential, for example for the matplotlib contour function. I can't do things like this:

```
result = np.sum(crack_list.get_potential(z))
```

Right now I'm doing the 'traditional' way:

```
def potential_value(z, crack_list):
     potential = complex(0, 0)

     for element in crack_list:
     potential = potential + element.get_potential(z)

    return potential
```

and if I use a for loop, it says that the element crack is not iterable. Let's say that I try to

```
    x = np.linspace(self.x1, self.x2, self.step)
    y = np.linspace(self.y1, self.y2, self.step)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    Z = X +1j*Y

    F = np.vectorize(potential_value)
```

but here I have a problem:

```
   F(Z, crack_list)

   for element in crack_list:
      TypeError: 'crack' object is not iterable
```

How can I do that? Thanks.

EDIT: Thanks for the answers. I'm still getting to know list comprehension, so it's still beating me. Let's say that I want to change my implementation for list comprehension, so I change the function to

```
def potential_value(z_list, crack_list, u_flow):

return [np.sum([c.get_potential(z) for c in crack_list]) + u_flow.get_potential_no_c(z) for z in z_list]
```

Where I'm trying to use now two list comprehensions at the same time, so the potential would return an array with all the results for all the z_list variables - noting that z_list should be a list for complex types. Is there a way to do that for just one complex value in z_list, *without* having to pass a list with just one value? Or I have to do some kind of test?

Comment: Wait! You seem to be trying to iterate over a list of crack objects and not a single crack. It seems to me that crack_list contains not a list object but a single list object at that point. Can you verify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the `get_pot()` method not returning anything, it looks like you don't define `self.n` or `self.coeffs` anywhere. I'm betting `coeffs` is meant to be a numpy vector, and `n` its length, and I'll assume they could vary between `Crack` objects just like `z1` and `z2`.

Based on those assumptions, I tweaked your class a little:

```
class Crack(object): # convention is to use capitalized class names

    def __init__(self, z1, z2, coeffs):
        self.z1 = z1
        self.z2 = z2
        self.coeffs = np.array(coeffs)
        self.n = len(coeffs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Crack(z1=%s, z2=%s, coeffs=%s)" % (self.z1, 
                                                   self.z2, 
                                                   self.coeffs)
    def get_big_Z(self, little_z):
        # this may not need to be its own function, unless you
        # use it separately from get_potential()
        return little_z - 0.5 * (self.z2 - self.z1)

    def get_potential(self, z):
        Z = self.get_big_Z(z)
        return (np.sum(np.arange(self.n) * self.coeffs * 
                       (1.0 / (np.sqrt(Z - 1.0) * np.sqrt(Z + 1.0))) * 
                       ((Z - np.sqrt(Z - 1.0) * np.sqrt(Z + 1.0)) ** 
                       np.arange(self.n))) * 
                (2.0 / (self.z2 - self.z1))
                )
```

Now, suppose you have (or can generate) a list of the `z1`, `z2`, and `coeffs` values for each `Crack`:

```
>>> # dummy information, this makes three Crack objects
...
>>> z1_values = [3.0, 1.1, 0.2]
>>> z2_values = [0.01, 0.02, 0.03]
>>> coeff_values = [[1.1,1.0],
...                 [2.2,2.0],
...                 [3.3,3.0]]
```

The `coeff` lists are converted to `ndarray` when the object is instantiated.

You can make `crack_list` with the built-in function [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) like this:

```
>>> crack_list = map(Crack, z1_values, z2_values, coeff_values)
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(crack_list)
[Crack(z1=3.0, z2=0.01, coeffs=[ 1.1  1. ]),
 Crack(z1=1.1, z2=0.02, coeffs=[ 2.2  2. ]),
 Crack(z1=0.2, z2=0.03, coeffs=[ 3.3  3. ])]
```

Then you can compute the total potential for some `z` values, say `z = 5.0` or `z = 3.14` like:

```
>>> def total_potential(z, cracks):
...     return sum(c.get_potential(z) for c in cracks)
...
>>>
>>> print total_potential(5.0, crack_list)
-0.772861759407
>>> print total_potential(3.14, crack_list)
-1.99073949493
```

Voila. As a check, I'd also do some pen-and-paper calculations just to be sure that big equation is doing what it should be doing.

Answer (score 5):

Object to be iterable needs to have `__iter__()` method, which returns an iterator (or sequence). Iterator should implement method `next()`, which will yield elements or `raise StopIteration` is there are no more elements. As simple as that.

Comment: If `__iter__` returns anything other than an iterator, such as a non-iterator sequence, iter() will raise TypeError.

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't see that your `get_pot` method returns anything.  It should end with `return result` i think.

Second, stop-gap measure would be to iterate over your list of objects:

```
[e.get_pot(i) for i in range(10)]
```

But ideally, since you are using numpy, you should get your class to accept arrays (which it looks like it might already).  See what happens when you input `sz1`, `sz2`, and `z` as equal-shape 2D arrays.  The, if you sum over just one axis, `get_pot` should then return an iterable array.  This would avoid creating lists of instances and take advantage of speedups that numpy offers.  (The effectiveness of this solution is a bit dependent on the number of crack instances you have and how often you create and destroy new instances)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of potentials with a list comprehension, replacing

```
result = np.sum(crack_list.get_potential(z))
```

with

```
result = np.sum([elem.get_potential(z) for elem in crack_list])
```

Map and reduce can also be used in this context.